# Alexa skill Python Flask ask and SocketIO with Unity

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, socket.io, alexa-skills-kit

I have created a custom Alexa skill which will play animation in unity based on user input.

My Alexa skill is tunneled using ngrok service, which is providing me https link that https link is used to connect skill with unity.

Now I want to configure my skill like, after animation is completed in unity, I want to call method in python which will trigger some intent if user not say anything.

I am able to call user defined method in python file and able to print text on console but the speech_text or reprompt_text is not working in same method.

Even I am not getting any python code which will call specific intent in python file not based on user input but based on animation condition.

So how can I call Intent from python code.

example :

take an example of human walking, talking, jumping, running animation in unity.
Lets say I opened my skill and said to play walking animation....walking animation is of 6 seconds....after animation is completed....if user not say anything then Alexa should need to call another intent which will call another animation...animation is, human is saying I have another animation also like talking and etc.

This reprompt functionality I don't want from reprompt_text in python as I kept echo dot session ON in background using 1 min blank audio file playing each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot trigger an intent from Alexa without a user interaction. And a session will be open only for 8 seconds, after that the reprompt, again 8 secs and session will end. Unfortunately we cannot modify this session timeout. So if a user didn't respond, it is anyway going to end after the response is played and your service will receive a `SessionEndedRequest`. So in your case you can make use of this `SessionEndedRequest` once, but it is not recommended. You can always include some backend logic to check whether you receive an intent request and play the next animation if you dont. But, you will never know whether the user is listening or not.

Another alternative would be to ask the user itself after the animation is played

Ex:

(playing animation for 6 secs)

> [break for 6 secs] ***Shall I play the next video?***

(you can also include a re prompt)

In this way you can keep the user engaged and if the user didn't respond, you can gracefully exit.

More on `SessionEndedRequest` [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/handle-requests-sent-by-alexa.html#sessionendedrequest)